# Running R Shiny Server in Docker - Getting error in dyn.load

Tags: r, docker, shiny-server

I am trying to set up my R Shiny-Server instance in a docker container to backup it more easily. I was able to download and install the necessary packages and dependencies but am getting an error now, when trying to access my app:

```
Warning: Error in dyn.load: unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/sodium/libs/sodium.so':
  libsodium.so.23: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
  48: dyn.load
  47: library.dynam
  46: loadNamespace
  45: match.fun
  44: sapply
  43: eval_tidy
  42: tibble_quos
  41: tibble::tibble
   1: runApp
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
  unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/sodium/libs/sodium.so':
  libsodium.so.23: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

For my docker container I have created the following persistent volumes:

volumes:

```
  - /volume1/docker/shiny/srv:/srv/shiny-server:rw

  - /volume1/docker/shiny/var:/var/log:rw

  - /volume1/docker/shiny/usr:/usr/local/lib/R/site-library:rw
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Posting the image name and tag you use may help you get faster answers.

Answer (score 0):

So after months of trial and error I finally got it working. In case anybody else has the same problem, the solution was to install a bunch of essential packages that were missing from the official docker image. I installed the following using:

```
apt-get update -qq && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \
libxml2-dev \
libcairo2-dev \
libsqlite3-dev \
libpq-dev \
libssh2-1-dev \
unixodbc-dev \
r-cran-v8 \
libv8-dev \
net-tools \
libprotobuf-dev \
protobuf-compiler \
ibjq-dev \
libudunits2-0 \
libudunits2-dev \
libgdal-dev \
libssl-dev
```

Aftwards I updated them using:

```
apt-get update && \
apt-get upgrade -y && \
apt-get clean
```

With these packages installed and updated, the web apps started working perfectly fine.